# Re-installing slate tile in an entry hall

Tags: tile, slate

We moved into this home about 25 years ago.  It is a "Mid-century modern" with green, gray, and red slate tiles in the entry.  When we moved in, some of the tile were loose and we had a tile-guy take them up and put them back down.  In about 5 years, the same thing...take up and re-install.  We have had this done 4 times and need to do it again.  These are reputable tile-guys -- premier floor covering/tile people in the area.  One thing...they always use mortar to set the tiles.  I asked about using mastic instead of mortar, but they always say "no."  I have installed lots of ceramic tile over the years and used mastic & grout.  None have ever come up.

What are my guys doing wrong?

Comment: what is under the tiles?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of the damage? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.